# Convert htaccess rewrite rules to Nginx issues

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I need assistance converting the following htaccess rules to Nginx.

```
AddHandler php5-script .php .html .html
AddType text/html .php .html .html
Opt0ions -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.php/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So far i have the following but dont know how to implement this within Nginx:

```
# nginx configuration
error_page 403 /index.php;
autoindex off;
location / {
if ($script_filename !~ "-f"){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1;
}
if ($http_host ~* "^www\.(.*)$"){
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 redirect;
}
}
```

The i had converted at http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Is the converted rewrite rules above correct? And how can i implement these with Nginx?